# Permanently in while loop c# , Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, while-loop

with my code, I'm supposed to be able to call a question from my file at random and not reuse that question again.

But for some reason I'm stuck in the while loop and after a few hours of searching I still can't see why, so I hope you guys can help me out.
(he gets stuck after he generated 8 questions)

Code (for the generatequestion one, if you need more I can paste it but I hope this gives enough information):

```
lineCount = File.ReadLines(pad).Count();
questions = new string[lineCount, 2];


public string GenerateQuestion(int total)
    {
        if (total <= 10)
        {
            Random ran = new Random();
            questionNumber = ran.Next(lineCount);
            while (previousQuestions.Contains(questionNumber))
            {
                questionNumber = ran.Next(lineCount);
            }

        }
        previousQuestions[questionCount] = questionNumber;
        questionCount++;
        return questions[questionNumber, 0];
    }
```

Comment: Better just [shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) your question list, that'd be easier.

Comment: 1) learn to debug your code, 2) think what happens when all possible random numbers generated correspond to a previous question...

Comment: I did debug, how else did I know he is stuck in the while loop :)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski But that just shuffles, it doesn't remove the question I already used right? I'm trying to have different questions all the time.

Comment: How many questions are present in your input file? The purpose of that <=10 is not clear.

Comment: @Steve depends on the file but it can go from 10 to 1000+ questions, the <=10 is the total (because in the main class I only use 10 questions)

Comment: @Daan shuffle the list, then just use the `n` first questions :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You could make a method to return the lines in the file in random order.</s>

```
public string[] GetQuestionsInRandomOrder()
{
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt");
    var rnd = new Random();
    lines = lines.OrderBy(line => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
    return lines;
}
```

Then as you use the questions you can remove them from the array.

```
var isRemoved = Array.remove(array, item);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397721%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

This is easier that what I had before and will give greater control. I would create a class for this and this example is a starting point. You can add more functionality as you go along. By having a class to do all this work you can add methods to do additional features later on without having to rewrite code.

```
public class Logic
{
    public List<string> AllQuestionsInRandomOrder { get; set; } 
    public List<string> QuestionsThatHaveBeenRemoved { get; set; }

    public Logic()
    {
        QuestionsThatHaveBeenRemoved = new List<string>();
        AllQuestionsInRandomOrder = GetQuestionsInRandomOrder().ToList();
    }

    public string GetUnusedQuestion()
    {
        var question =
            AllQuestionsInRandomOrder.FirstOrDefault(x => !QuestionsThatHaveBeenRemoved.Contains(x));
        QuestionsThatHaveBeenRemoved.Add(question);
        return question;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetQuestionsInRandomOrder()
    {
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt").ToList();
        var rnd = new Random();
        lines = lines.OrderBy(line => rnd.Next()).ToList();
        return lines;
    }

    public void RemoveQuestion(List<string> questions, string questionToRemove)
    {
        questions.Remove(questionToRemove);
    }
}
```

I would avoid using loops and break the problem into separate methods or functions. It will make it easier to debug. This implementation does not separate the questions and answers out, so you will need to add a method that returns a dictionary of the questions and answers.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var questions = new Questions();
            var firstQuestion = questions.GetUnusedQuestion();
            Console.WriteLine(firstQuestion);
        }
    }

    class Questions
    {

        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public static List<string> AllQuestionsAndAnswersFromFile { get; set; } 
        public List<string> AllQuestionsInRandomOrder { get; set; }
        public List<string> QuestionsThatHaveBeenRemoved { get; set; }

        public Questions()
        {
            FileName = "text.txt";
            QuestionsThatHaveBeenRemoved = new List<string>();
            AllQuestionsAndAnswersFromFile = new List<string>();
            ReadQuestionsFromFile();
            AllQuestionsInRandomOrder = GetQuestionsInRandomOrder().ToList();
        }

        public string GetUnusedQuestion()
        {
            var question =
                AllQuestionsInRandomOrder.FirstOrDefault(x => QuestionsThatHaveBeenRemoved.Contains(x));
            QuestionsThatHaveBeenRemoved.Add(question);
            return question;
        }

        private static IEnumerable<string> GetQuestionsInRandomOrder()
        {
            var lines = AllQuestionsAndAnswersFromFile;
            var rnd = new Random();
            lines = lines.OrderBy(line => rnd.Next()).ToList();
            return lines;
        }

        public void RemoveQuestion(List<string> questions, string questionToRemove)
        {
            questions.Remove(questionToRemove);
        }

        public void ReadQuestionsFromFile()
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(FileName, Encoding.Default))
            {
                var text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                var lines = text.Split('=');
                foreach (var s in lines)
                {
                    AllQuestionsAndAnswersFromFile.Add(s);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah... I tried applying it but seems like I'm too stupid to do so, could you apply this to my code if possible?

Comment: I've restructured my response, basically this class will get an unused question and also keep track of the ones you have used.

Comment: Okay, I'm starting to get it, but do I have to keep my original code or just completly throw that away, because I still need to split the question up in 2 (since in the file, 1 line = question + answer and I just need the question to return)
I also got a readQuestions method already, throw that one away aswell then?

Comment: I wouldn't throw it away if it has functionality, you could move that functionality into this class. Basically, make a method to get just the questions and then pass that into the method to get the questions in random order.

Comment: I'm sure this would work and I appreciate the effort you're putting in to help me but I just don't get how to apply this to my code, is it possible for you to add it to my code if I give it? (I'll add the full class in a pastebin then)

Comment: Sure, no problem, you could ask as another question.

Comment: What do you need help with? I see you are reading in the file to get the questions and answers.

Comment: It stays in the while loop permanently like said in the opening post and I don't get how I can implement your solution to my code to fix it.

Comment: I would not use a while loop unless you absolutely have to, look at my implementation and notice how I break everything into a method. I could have broken it apart more but this is just an example.

Comment: General rule of thumb, if I can't debug or find a solution to the problem, the code is too complex. Good code is clean, easy to read, and each method does exactly one thing.

Comment: I think this willw ork, but where do you use the RemoveQuestion method?

Answer (score 1):

When you run out of questions, let's see what

```
while (previousQuestions.Contains(questionNumber))
{
    questionNumber = ran.Next(lineCount);
}
```

actually does:

- Is `questionNumber` one of the questions we already asked?
- Yes, get a new question number. (because we've asked all the questions)
- Is `questionNumber` one of the questions we already asked?
- yes, get a new question number. (because we've asked all the questions)

A solution in this case would be to shuffle your questions that you return, removing them as you grab them.

Comment: @JonKittell has a reasonable implementation for the shuffle / retrieve step.